# python code equivalent to saving a text file by pressing Ctrl+S

Tags: python-3.x

I've written the value of a variable called event to a text file called 1.txt in python as below:

```
event_file = open('1.txt', 'w')
event = df_events[0][3]
event_file.write(event)
event_file.flush()
os.fsync(event_file)
event_file.close()
```

the value of event variable is just a string: PAPI_L1_ICM
when I open the 1.txt file, I can see that it stores PAPI_L1_ICM but the file size is 11 bytes.  But when I write a code later that reads 1.txt file, the file content is not properly read. Then when I open the 1.txt file and press Ctrl + S to save it, the file size increases to 12 bytes, and its content is properly accessed by the later code.

Now, is there any python code that can work as Ctrl + S ? or did I miss anything in my code snippet above to properly save 1.txt file? The value of event variable is coming from a dataframe that reads another file.

I used python jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The string has 11 characters, so why do you think it should be 12 bytes? The text editor you're saving it with is probably adding a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - not every editor does this, and whether it's desirable depends on your use-case.

Comment: Thank you so much, kaya3. Actually increase in file size is not my concern, that is what I just observed. But my main concern is that when I open 1.txt file and save by pressing Ctrl + S, then my later code can read the file properly... I am wondering  whether I miss anything in the code snippet above to write the 1.txt file, which would not require pressing the ctrl+s...